# popToRootViewController when application enters background

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

In the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` of my application , the code is

```
   _homeViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc]init];
    UINavigationController*  _navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_homeViewController];
    [self.window setRootViewController:_navigationController];
    [_navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

and in the `HomeViewController` , I am having two buttons, If the button is pressed , I am presenting the ViewController. If button1 is pressed , the code is

```
if (_detailsViewController == nil)
            _detailsViewController = [[DetailsViewController alloc]init];

       [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:_detailsViewController animated:YES];
```

Now when I am in the detailsViewController and I pressing the iPhone Home button, in the same class I am using the `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` and calling a method to execute the following line

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

So I thought when I open the application again, I can see the HomeViewController, but it doesn't work. Please help me !!

Comment: I think you need to dismiss first presented view controller, then popToRootViewControllerAnimated will work.

Comment: Ya. Dismissing viewcontroller might work. But what if I am in the 5th viewcontroller and I am trying to come to the HomeViewController

Comment: If you have presented from navigation controller then you need to dismiss first then only you can pop to home. If you are presenting more then one VC then you can track them in array and while dismiss remove from that array. I was facing same situation and I have worked with this way. Not sure If there is better way to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the reason why I am not able to pop to the root view is , I am presenting the ViewController in between, If the ViewController comes along with the navigation controller, i.e  , if the ViewController is pushed as a navigation controller then i can pop to the root view controller

Answer (score 0):

When you enter the background, save a piece of state information, and when you re-enter the foreground, check that information, and if the flag is set then do the pop there with no animation.

Comment: But popToRootViewController doesn't seems to be working now. Because, I have added one more button in the DetailsViewController like a back button. When that Back button is clicked, I have added this line [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]; , but it is not coming to the rootview. Why ? Am I missing something :(

Comment: It seems to me your are doing this as you move to the background and the view controllers are not going to get a lot of time to respond. I don't exactly know why it doesn't work - I'd have to write my own app and play with it. I'm just saying if you invert the problem - deal with the GUI change when you come back. It probably is keeping that message pending as you are showing a modal view controller, and you didn't dismiss it. If you dismiss it, then pop, that might work, But still the gui will be all moving around as you go away - it would seem to me better to handle when coming back.